# What does $\Bbb{R} \times \Bbb{R}$ denote in sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Let set $A$ be : $A = \{(a, b) \in \Bbb{R} \times \Bbb{R} : |a – 5| < 1 \text{ and }|b – 5| < 1\}$

What exactly does $(a, b) \in \Bbb{R} \times \Bbb{R}$
mean here ?

Comment: It means $a\in R$ and $b\in R$. By definition, $R\times R$ is the set of pairs $(a, b)$ with $a,b\in R$.

Comment: If you prefer, you could replace $\Bbb{R} \times \Bbb{R}$ by $\Bbb{R}^2$, if you are more familiar with this notation.

Comment: $(a,b)$ is a *pair* of reals, like (left shoe, right shoe) is a pair of shoes.

Comment: Cf. [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbb{R}^2 = \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R} = \{(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}\} = \{(a,b), a\in \mathbb{R}, b\in \mathbb{R}\}$